# How to translate a java jna interface to kotlin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, kotlin, jna

I am trying to port to kotlin the [openvr binding](https://github.com/java-graphics/openvr)

I have the following in java:

```
public class IVRSystem extends Structure {

    /**
     * C type : GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback*
     */
    public IVRSystem.GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize;

    public interface GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback extends Callback {

        void apply(IntBuffer pnWidth, IntBuffer pnHeight);
    };
}
```

Intellij translates it automatically to

```
var GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize: IVRSystem.GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback? = null

interface GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback : Callback {

    fun apply(pnWidth: IntBuffer, pnHeight: IntBuffer)
}
```

I changed it then to:

```
fun getRecommendedRenderTargetSize(pnWidth: IntBuffer, pnHeight: IntBuffer) = GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback.apply(pnWidth, pnHeight)

interface GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback : Callback {

    fun apply(pnWidth: IntBuffer, pnHeight: IntBuffer)
}
```

but it complains

> unresolved reference: apply

Why? How can I fix that?

For reference, C++ code

```
class IVRSystem
{
    public:
         virtual void GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize( uint32_t *pnWidth, uint32_t *pnHeight ) = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize_callback` is an interface.

The interface itself does not have an `apply(IntBuffer, IntBuffer)` function but defines such a function for implementing instances of the interface.

You'll need an instance of an object which implements your interface in order to be able to call its "apply" function but such would not be a "port" of the Java code you provided.

Comment: You mean `ivrSystem.GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize.apply(...)`? Because it's supposed to be like this